# Hodrick and Prescott (HP) filter in R

Tags: r, time-series, economics, trend

I'm applying the HP filter to time series data to remove the cyclical component of a time series (TS) from raw data. Data do have a yearly frequency.
I write in R:

```
lambda=100 #penalty term
cycle= hpfilter(v1,freq=lambda)$cycle
```

where v1 is my TS data. In this way, I get the cyclical component.

Do you agree with me that is common practice to set lambda=100 when you deal with annual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, usually we use 100 for yearly data. See "tips" section in (https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/hpfilter.html).

Comment: This can be psoted as comment